# If I create custom Button with material-ui ButtonGroup doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

As you can understand from the title I created a custom button for myself with Button in `@material-ui/core`. But when I add these custom buttons to ButtonGroup they don't act as group.

**My Custom Button:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "@material-ui/core";
import CloudUploadIcon from '@material-ui/icons/CloudUpload';
import PencilIcon from '@material-ui/icons/LinkSharp'
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const icons = { "cloud": <CloudUploadIcon />, "pencil": <PencilIcon /> }
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        padding: 30,
        fontSize: 18,
        '&:hover': {
            boxShadow: '0 0 0.1rem 0.1rem rgba(25,25,25,1)'
        }
    }
}));

function __Button(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    {
        return (
            <Button variant="outlined" startIcon={icons[props.icon]} className={classes.root}>
                {props.text}
            </Button>
        )
    }
}

export default __Button;
```

**My Usage:**

```
<ButtonGroup size="large" aria-label="small outlined button group">
    <__Button text={"I will paste links!"} icon={"pencil"} />
    <__Button text={"I will upload a text file!"} icon={"cloud"} />
</ButtonGroup>
```

**Issue Image:**
[image: Buttons are not grouped]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass all the other props that comes from `ButtonGroup` to `Button`.

```
function __Button({ icon, text, ...otherProps }) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Button
      variant="outlined"
      startIcon={icons[icon]}
      className={classes.root}
      {...otherProps} // passing props from ButtonGroup to Button
    >
      {text}
    </Button>
  );
}
```

Here is a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-6jv59).

[image]